# How to compare count of two tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Having troble trying to compare count from two tables (using SQLite).

Supposing I have tables like:

Objects (NumId is *Primary key*)

| NumId | Object_category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | permanent |
| 2 | borrowed |
| 3 | borrowed |
| 4 | borrowed |
| 5 | borrowed |

Borrowed
(NumObj is *Foreign Key/Primary Key* referring Object table)

| NumObj | Collection_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | collection_alpha |
| 3 | collection_betha |
| 4 | collection_betha |
| 5 | collection_betha |

Query I need to perform is:

> "What are the collections with higher number of borrowed objects than
> quantity of permanent objets?"

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT Collection_name FROM Borrowed
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(Collection_name) FROM Borrowed)> 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Objects WHERE Object_category = 
'permanent')
```

It is returning the values from the column, not working as supposed (hould have returned the 'collection_betha' for owning 3 objects, greater than number of existing permanent objects that is 1).

Comment: You can conditionally count the join to get both numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a join will help

```
SELECT Borrowed.Collection_name
FROM Borrowed 
JOIN Objects 
ON Objects.NumId= Borrowed.NumObj
GROUP BY Borrowed.Collection_name 
HAVING COUNT(NumObj) > 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Objects WHERE Object_category = 'permanent')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT b.Collection_name
FROM Borrowed b
INNER JOIN Objects o
    ON o.NumId = b.NumObj
GROUP BY b.Collection_name
HAVING SUM(o.Object_category = 'borrowed') > SUM(o.Object_category = 'permanent');
```